# How to override Authorize attribute in ASP.MVC 5 with multiple authorization conditions?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am implementing authorization/authentication in a MVC project. They problem I am facing is that there are many conditions for a login user like `roles`, `positions`, `permissions` and some others. I thought the best way is to override `AthorizeAttribute` and set all logic in there by passing the data as string arrays in constructor and validate them but I do have more than 100 permissions and more than 40 positions which makes this attribute almost useless because I can not write in every action for example 60 position etc.

I thought I could group them somehow but I can see it is not a good point because all actions are dynamic and I would make tons of groups for `user permissions` and `user positions`.

I red in some posts for creating a base controller to make all validations there but I am using ASP.NET Identity and I don`t like going in 'old' fashion way...

If anybody had any situation like that before I would be grateful if you share your solution!

**EDIT - Adding code example**

```
public class XAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    public XAuthorizeAttribute() { }

    public XAuthorizeAttribute(params string[] roles)
    {
        Roles = string.Join(",", roles.Select(x => x));
    }

    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        bool isAuthenticAttribute =
            (filterContext.ActionDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(XAuthorizeAttribute), true) ||
            filterContext.ActionDescriptor.ControllerDescriptor.IsDefined(typeof(XAuthorizeAttribute), true)) &&
            filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated;
        if (!isAuthenticAttribute) return;
        UrlHelper urlHelper = new UrlHelper(filterContext.RequestContext);
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            IdentityManager.SignInManager.AuthenticationManager.SignOut(
                DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie, DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ExternalCookie);
        }
        filterContext.Result = 
            new RedirectResult(urlHelper.Action("Index", "Home", new {area = ""}));
        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}
```

Here is the action...

```
[XAuthorize("Administrator", "articlelists", "HOD Engineering", "HOD Interior"....)]
public ActionResult Index()
{
    return View("Index");
}
```

As you can see I only put 4 roles, just imagine putting 60 roles and permissions etc.... This is just a demo to get the idea because in my project I do not have only roles as I do have here.

Comment: Can you add a practical example of what you're seeking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of hard coding roles into attributes it may be better to create a custom generic [XAuthorizeAction] attribute that would start off the process of checking your database for permission configuration.

Step 1.) Configure database to know permissions for action level calls

Step 2.) Create authorization attribute for controller actions that need this level of permission control

Step 3.) Inside attribute determine the caller and the calling controller and action

Step 4.) Query the database for this controller and action to determine the actions permissions.

Step 5.) Query the database for the users permissions and see if they match